# Did the new login sound not make it into 12.04?

Tags: login

Running 12.04 for the first time today, I still have the old login sound.  (Well, technically I don't have any login sound at all, oddly.  Nothing in startup apps for it.  When I do a file search for Gnome Login, I find a sound file for it but it's the old sound.) I was looking forward to the new sound, are there still plans to implement it?

Comment: Do you have a link to what the new login sound is supposed to sound like? I don't think there is a new login sound.

Comment: @JorgeCastro, the new log in sound was decided a while ago, but I don't think 12.04 got it for some reason. To my understanding they were planning on making a new sound theme around the chosen log in sound, so maybe that isn't finished yet. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/new-ubuntu-sound-theme-winner-chosen/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change it;

First, record the startup sound you looking for:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJw178Iunk4

You could convert the video to MP3 (youtube-mp3.org), and edit the sound file.  Export it to an MP3, an place it in /usr/share/gnome/autostart.

Then follow these steps:
http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/03/how-to-play-custom-login-sound-mp3-on.html

This is for 11.10, but on 12.04, that worked for me!  This haven't made the boot time slower or anything like that.

Enjoy ;)